# SSIS Container executions details?

Tags: ssis

In integration services package: is there a way to know the sequence of executions?

I want to execute a package where we get zip files into a folder. But we then need to pick files from that folder for further processing.

How could that be achieved?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you clarify further?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1):

Precedence Constraints will determine the order in which objects in a package execute.  See the [Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/precedence-constraints?view=sql-server-2017) for more details.